# JFrame is not showing up after calling this method (Who throws IOException)

Tags: java, jframe, ioexception

I have this java `JFrame` to show the current time and the date. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dTmU.jpg) is a screenshot.
But I have made another method to do some tricks **(to copy files from a directory to another directory on my pc)**. I know this is silly, but I need that for a project. I have call this `method` in the `class constructor`. When I call it, the `JFrame` won't show up. but the process inside the method is running without any problem.

Here is my code sample of method named **processOne()** and method **copyCompleted()** which has been calling inside method **processOne()**

```
private static void processOne() throws IOException {
    final String directoryWindows = "C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\Check me";
    File directory = new File(directoryWindows);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();     
        for (File file : fList) {
            if ((file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")) || (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")) || (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".gif")) || (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".png"))) {
                File source = new File(file.getPath());
                File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\Banu\\" + file.getName());
                if (dest.exists() == false) {
                    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
                    copyCompleted(dest.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Exists");
                }
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                file.getAbsolutePath();
            } else {
           System.out.println("ELSE");
                File source = new File(file.getPath());
                File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\Banu\\" + file.getName());
                if (dest.exists() == false) {
                    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
                    copyCompleted(dest.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Exists");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Finished!");
        jButton1.setForeground(Color.blue);
}
```

this is the "**copyCompleted(String filePath)**" method.

```
public static void copyCompleted(String filePath) {

        String fileStr = filePath;
        File ff = new File(fileStr);

        boolean copyCompleted = false;

        if (ff.exists()) {

            while (true) {

                RandomAccessFile ran = null;

                try {
                    ran = new RandomAccessFile(ff, "rw");
                    copyCompleted = true;
                    break;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("  still copying ........... " + ex.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    if (ran != null) {
                        try {
                            ran.close();
                            //System.out.println("End");
                        } catch (IOException ex) {

                        }
                    }

                    ran = null;
                }

            }

            if (copyCompleted) {
                System.out.println("Copying");
                jButton1.setForeground(Color.green);

            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No exists");
        }
        //System.out.println("End2");
    }
```

►Since the time I'm calling my method "**processOne()**" , my program's "**main method**" showing up a warning to put a `try-catch` so I put it like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

     //look and feel setting code is here

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                ClockTime dialog = new ClockTime(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClockTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my Coding???

**Everything works fine but the `JFrame` isn't showing up :(

Comment: You are likely blocking the EDT preventing it from processing any GUI related events. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer: can you specify the error I'm doing here?

Comment: Read the links, understand what changes you've made that are now causing you issues, do some research into copying files in Swing